# three.js functions as modules on node.js

Tags: node.js, module, compiler-errors, three.js

I am trying to build a visualization in a file called visualization where I've made everything into module export functions.

I have a file called app and when I run it, calling those functions (say drawSomething), I get an error like this:

```
$ node app.js
```

THREE.WebGLRenderer 59dev

c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules\three\three.js:18671
var _canvas = parameters.canvas !== undefined ? parameters.canvas : document.c
                                                                    ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at new THREE.WebGLRenderer (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\node_modules
\three\three.js:18671:70)
    at Object. (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\visualization.js:
15:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (c:\Users\Brian\documents\visualizer\app.js:19:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

I am not exactly sure what this means and why there is such a problem. If someone is familiar with using three.js with node.js, please give me some pointers.

Thanks,
Brian

P.S. - I am doing this in a very hackish way, which is bad. However, I understand how three.js can be used to render things in an HTML file, I am just not sure of the process to turn everything into functions and call them from another .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Three.js and WebGL need to be running from a browser environment in order to work. Your error seems to be about a missing `document`, which is a browser specific global variable referring to the current HTML DOM etc. I think in addition to `document` and `window`, node.js is missing various other browser objects/API's used by Three.js like `canvas`, and most importantly, WebGL canvas context.

You might have some luck using only CanvasRenderer, if there are some libraries available for node.js to support canvas. Also PhantomJS, a command line scriptable browser, should be able to support CanvasRenderer and may be possible to hook into node.js. A similar project called SlimerJS should support also WebGLRenderer, but that is using a full browser under the hood.